# Transfer money from one stripe account to another stripe account

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

How can I transfer money from one stripe account to another stripe account ?
I am following this code from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/special-case-transfers):

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY);
\Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => "hkd",
  'destination' => {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
));
```

But getting this error:

> Type: Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest
>
> Message: Insufficient
>   funds in Stripe account. In test mode, you can add funds to your
>   available balance  (bypassing your pending balance) by creating a
>   charge with 4000 0000 0000 0077 as the card number. You can use the
>   the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more
>   details, see stripe.com /docs/api#balance).

**But in my test account from where I have to transfer there is around $3000 and still I am getting the above error.**

see this: [test-account-balance](http://i.prntscr.com/567d20e21e6f4c29acce9950f51fd98e.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens with me also. My mistake was I was using live secret key.
you can check

1. You are using test connected Account Id (You have to connect the
   customer in test mode also. Live and Test connected Ids are
   different).
2. You are using Test secret key for the testing.
3. Create one customer with card no. 4000 0000 0000 0077 and charge it. Using this balance you can transfer amount to another account.

Comment: I am working only test mode for now. and i am using test secret key only

Comment: So you have connected the another stripe account in test mode. cross check it.

Comment: ok I got the solution just create one customer with card no. 4000 0000 0000 0077 and charge it after that using this balance you can transfer the amount

Comment: this is not customers, there is connected account only

Comment: In your stripe account Create new customer and attach the stripe card 4000 0000 0000 0077. charge this customer for 3000 and amount will come in your account. you can transfer this amount only

Comment: I don't need to create new customer. need to create connected account. both are different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120429/discussion-between-lav-kumar-vishwakarma-and-pathik-vejani).

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can only transfer funds *from* a platform's account *to* one of its connected accounts (not the other way around).

When accepting payments on behalf of a connected account, you need to [create the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), either [directly on the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-directly) (using the [`Stripe-Account` header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header)) or [through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform) (using the `destination` parameter). In both cases, you'd use the `application_fee` parameter to (optionally) take your cut out of the transaction.

If you want to transfer funds outside of a charge, this is known as a [special-case transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/special-case-transfers). As the name implies, these transfers should only be used in certain specific scenarios and are subject to some constraints -- most importantly, the volume of special-case transfers must stay under 10% of the overall volume processed by your platform.

In order to transfer funds, the funds must be available. Generally, when you accept a charge, the funds from the charge are initially "pending". After a delay (which varies by country and by account), they become "available" and can be transferred.

In test mode, you can create charges with the special testing number `4000 0000 0000 0077` so that funds become immediately available. This way you don't have to wait to test transfers.

You can check the status of both parts of your account's balance ("pending" and "available") with the ["retrieve balance"](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_balance) API call.

Comment: total volume is avalible find?

Comment: see this: http://i.prntscr.com/567d20e21e6f4c29acce9950f51fd98e.png $3118 is availble fund?

Comment: You can check the status of both parts of your account's balance ("pending" and "available") with the "retrieve balance" API call: https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_balance.